# Installing PyXML on ubuntu

Tags: python, package

I need to install PyXML on python 2.7.5,

```
:~/Desktop/PyXML-0.8.4$ sudo python setup.py install 
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_xmlplus.parsers.pyexpat' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DXML_NS=1 -DXML_DTD=1 -DBYTEORDER=1234 -DXML_CONTEXT_BYTES=1024 -Iextensions/expat/lib -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c extensions/pyexpat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extensions/pyexpat.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DXML_NS=1 -DXML_DTD=1 -DBYTEORDER=1234 -DXML_CONTEXT_BYTES=1024 -Iextensions/expat/lib -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c extensions/expat/lib/xmlparse.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extensions/expat/lib/xmlparse.o
extensions/expat/lib/xmlparse.c:75:2: error: #error memmove does not exist on this platform, nor is a substitute available
 #error memmove does not exist on this platform, nor is a substitute available
  ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How I can fix this error?
EDIT:

```
~/Desktop/pyhrf-0.2$ sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
[sudo] password for vahid: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.7-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
```

EDIT2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-xml
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-xml
```

Comment: you have marked the wrong answer as accepted. please correct it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best shot is to add `#define HAVE_MEMMOVE 1` at the top of `/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h`.

Refer : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1238244/

Comment: wat a surprise puneet sir +1 ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 12.10:

```
sudo apt-get install pip

sudo pip install PyXML

Downloading/unpacking PyXML
Running setup.py egg_info for package PyXML
```